# three.jsのサンプルにあるblenderファイルが読み込めない

Tags: blender, three.js

three.jsの
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/models/skinned/marine
このページにあるmarine_anims_core.blendをblenderで開きたいのですが、未対応のファイルフォーマットですと言われて開けません。
なんとか開けるようにする方法ないですか？

Comment: Blender 2.77(Mac)では開けましたよ。ファイルが破損したか、お持ちのBlenderが古いのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

すいませんでしたーーーー。
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/models/skinned/marine
にある
marine_anims_core.blend
のリンクを右クリックして、名前を付けてリンク先を保存でやってましたーーーー。
このリンクを辿ってその先のDownloadからやるのを失念してました。
なやみました。ショボくてほんとすいません。